# GUI Label, ListBox,Button appear in different frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Hi i am trying to create a Python GUI with label,textbox,button and etc, below are my code that is working fine.

Problem: Beside my Button the rest(label,tb,listbox) are all displayed in another frame.. Is there a way to open and display all in just 1 frame?

```
from Tkinter import *
import webbrowser
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as Tk

def actionDirectory():
    webbrowser.open('C:\AgmPlots')

def actionOpenFile():
    print "Done"

win = Tk.Toplevel()  #Open up connection and declare button and label
frame = Tk.Frame(master=win).grid(row=1, column=1)

Lb1 = Listbox(win)
Lb1.insert(1, "Python")
Lb1.insert(2, "Perl")
Lb1.insert(3, "C")
Lb1.insert(4, "PHP")
Lb1.insert(5, "JSP")
Lb1.insert(6, "Ruby")
Lb1.pack()
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='Open Folder', command=actionDirectory)
button1 = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='Open Text', command=actionOpenFile)
button.pack()
button1.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: As a side note, your code is an obvious mishmash of copied and pasted bits from elsewhere (you `import Tkinter as Tk` but also `from Tkinter import *`, etc.). Don't try to cram bits of code that you don't understand together; try to understand each bit well enough that you can write it yourself. Otherwise you'll end up... Well, writing code that asks for a new Frame and then wondering why you got a new Frame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out.

```
from Tkinter import *
import webbrowser
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as Tk

def actionDirectory():
    webbrowser.open('C:\AgmPlots')

def actionOpenFile():
    print "Done"

win = Tk.Tk()  #Open up connection and declare button and label
master=win

Lb1 = Listbox(win)
Lb1.insert(1, "Python")
Lb1.insert(2, "Perl")
Lb1.insert(3, "C")
Lb1.insert(4, "PHP")
Lb1.insert(5, "JSP")
Lb1.insert(6, "Ruby")
Lb1.pack()
button = Tk.Button(text='Open Folder', command=actionDirectory)
button1 = Tk.Button(text='Open Text', command=actionOpenFile)
button.pack()
button1.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what you did differently, rather than require the reader to go line-by-line to look for differences.

Comment: What is to purpose of `master=win`?

Answer (score 1):

`grid` / `pack` return nothing.

```
frame = Tk.Frame(master=win).grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Executing following line cause `frame` to be `None`; `Widget(master=frame, ...)` after than is like `Widget(master=None)` which cause that widget belong to the root window instead of another Toplevel window.

Replace above line as follow.

```
frame = Tk.Frame(master=win)
frame.pack()
```

---

Now, you get two windows, one (root window) and another created using `Toplevel`.

If you want just one window, replace following

```
win = Tk.Toplevel()
```

with:

```
win = Tk.Tk()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The only reason you have an extra frame is because you explicitly created one. Just don't do that.

Get rid of the `frame = …` line and you'll get rid of the other window. Use `master=win` instead of `master=frame` to put widgets into the main window instead of into the other frame.

Or, if you want to put a frame inside the top-level window, don't create a new Toplevel and put some things inside that but others inside the default one.